# Como fazer if de verificação para cadastro, no php?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
$nome_cad = $_POST["nome_ent_c"];
$cpf_cad = $_POST["cpf_ent_c"];
$tel_cad = $_POST["tel_ent_c"];
$end_cad = $_POST["end_ent_c"];
$invite_cad = $_POST["cod_convite"];
$codgerado = $_POST["codgerado"];
$senha = $_POST["senhacad"];
$username = $_POST["user_ent_c"];

$selectinvite = "select codinvitelogin from login";

$resultado_select = mysqli_query($conn, $selectinvite);
$resultado_select -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if($invite_cad == $resultado_select){
        
    $comandoSQL = "INSERT INTO login (nomelogin,cpflogin,telefone,endlogin,codigologinusado,codinvitelogin,senha,username) VALUES ('$nome_cad','$cpf_cad','$tel_cad','$end_cad','$invite_cad','$codgerado','$senha','$username');";
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<span style='color: green';>Administrador cadastrado com sucesso!</span>";
    header("Location: cadastrologin.php");   
    
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<span style='color: red';>Erro: Administrador nao cadastrado com sucesso!</span>";
    header("Location: cadastrologin.php");
}
```

Eu queria que quando o usuário digitasse o código de convite dele no *input* o programa verificasse se o código informado existe no banco; se for verdadeiro (existir), insere o cadastro. Se não existir, exibir mensagem de erro.

Esse código que eu fiz não retorna erros, mas também não funciona.

Comment: *fetch_all* retorna um *array*. É necessário informar o índice "codinvitelogin" ao verificar se a condição é verdadeira. Você também pode usar a *query* `SELECT codinvitelogin FROM login WHERE codinvitelogin = '$invite_cad';`. Utilize a função `mysqli_error` para verificar os possíveis erros

Answer (score 0):

Opa Bruno.

Primeiro, se sua versão do PHP for muito antiga, o fetch_all não funciona. Tipicamente fetch_assoc é mais usado.

De qualquer forma, um dos problemas é que seu $resultado_select não é uma string e você está comparando com uma string. Por mais que você filtre pra retornar apenas o campo codinvitelogin, o retorno de fetch_all é um vetor (pois ao se realizar um select, você pode ter várias linhas como retorno). Ou seja, seu if sempre vai dar falso.

Para mudar isso, precisaria correr pelo vetor e fazer a comparação com o campo diretamente, algo como:

```
foreach ($resultado_select as $linha) {
  if($invite_cad == $linha->codinvitelogin){ //você precisa falar com qual campo daquela linha vai comparar
    //código a ser executado;
  }    
}
```

No entanto, um jeito mais simples de fazer isso, seria procurar na tabela diretamente se existe algum registro com aqueles dados. Você pode fazer isso através de uma concatenação em query parecida com essa:

```
$query = "select codinvitelogin from login where codinvitelogin = " . $_POST["cod_convite"];
```

Logo, se houver retorno acima, significa que o código do usuário é válido, caso contrário, o retorno será de um vetor vazio.

```
if(empty($resultado_array)) //ou !empty() caso queira verificar em ordem contrária
    echo "Convite inválido"; 
else
    echo "Convite válido";
```

Answer (score 0):

**1 - Aproveitando sua rotina**

A função fetch_all() por padrão devolve um `array`

```
$resultado_select -> fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

veja como "printar" o array

```
$resultArray = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
print_r($resultArray);
```

Exemplo retornado

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [codinvitelogin] => 12345 ) [1] => Array ( [codinvitelogin] => 23456 ) [2] => Array ( [codinvitelogin] => 34567 ) [3] => Array ( [codinvitelogin] => 45678 ) [4] => Array ( [codinvitelogin] => 03422 ) [5] => Array ( [codinvitelogin] => 23478 ) )
```

Ao comparar a variável `$invite_cad` com o array com certeza sempre vai dar false

```
if($invite_cad == $resultado_select){
```

Utilize um foreach e verifique se no array existe o valor da variável `$invite_cad`

```
$result = "";

foreach ($resultArray as $item) {   // $resultArray é o array inicial
    if ($item['codinvitelogin'] === $invite_cad) {
        //se o valor da variavel $invite_cad existir no array atribuímos um valor a variável $result
        $result = "cadastrar";
        break;
    }
}
```

Vida que segue :-)

```
if($result == "cadastrar"){

    $comandoSQL = "INSERT .......             
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<span style='color: blue';>OK: Administrador cadastrado com sucesso!</span>";
    
}else{

       $_SESSION['msg'] = "<span style='color: red';>Erro: Administrador nao cadastrado com sucesso!</span>";

}

 header("Location: cadastrologin.php");
```

**2 - Uma forma mais direta**

```
<?php
session_start();

$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "root";
$senha = "";
$dbname = "bancotcc";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);


if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection pifada: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$invite_cad = $_POST["cod_convite"];


//Utilize a cláusula WHERE que é usada para extrair apenas os registros que atendem a uma condição especificada
$selectinvite = "select codinvitelogin from login WHERE codinvitelogin = '$invite_cad'";

$resultado_select = mysqli_query($conn, $selectinvite);

//resultado da query
$resultado_select = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_select);

if($invite_cad == $resultado_select['codinvitelogin']){

    $nome_cad = $_POST["nome_ent_c"];
    $cpf_cad = $_POST["cpf_ent_c"];
    $tel_cad = $_POST["tel_ent_c"];
    $end_cad = $_POST["end_ent_c"];
    $codgerado = $_POST["codgerado"];
    $senha = $_POST["senhacad"];
    $username = $_POST["user_ent_c"];
    
    $comandoSQL = "INSERT INTO login (nomelogin,cpflogin,telefone,endlogin,codigologinusado,codinvitelogin,senha,username)
    VALUES ('$nome_cad','$cpf_cad','$tel_cad','$end_cad','$invite_cad','$codgerado','$senha','$username')";
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $comandoSQL);  
    
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<span style='color: green';>OK: Administrador cadastrado com sucesso!</span>";
    
}else{
       $_SESSION['msg'] = "<span style='color: red';>Erro: Administrador nao cadastrado com sucesso!</span>";

}

header("Location: cadastrologin.php");

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Olá, boa noite! Estou tentando utilizar a forma mais direta, pois parece mais simples para mim, está 'funcionando', pois ele retorna que foi cadastrado com sucesso, mas quando eu coloco para inserir os dados no banco, da como cadastrado com sucesso, mas nao insere, saberia o pq? pfv

Comment: @Bruno, como é a string da conexão?

Comment: $servidor = "localhost";
 $usuario = "root";
 $senha = "";
 $dbname = "bancotcc";
 
 //Criar a conexao
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

Comment: @Bruno, viu a resposta editada? conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Sim, obrigada, de coraçao msm